# Vuejs : How to make a computed property which observe a list of items?

Tags: arrays, vuejs2, computed-properties

I want to synchronize data inside two arrays in my application. I am using vue.js.

My first array looks like that :

```
    var testLayout = [
        {"x":0,"y":0,"w":2,"h":2,"i":"0"},
        {"x":2,"y":0,"w":2,"h":4,"i":"1"}
    ];
```

And the second one which contains item object is like that :

```
    var items = [
        item {
            //other properties
            Position = {
                x,
                y,
                Width,
                Height,
                MinWidth,
                MaxWidth,
                MinHeight,
                MaxHeight
            }
        },
        ....
    ]
```

I want the properties inside the first array react to change from the second one and vice versa. 
I need to synchronize my data like that : `testLayout[...].myAnonymousObject.x <=> items[...].item.Position.x`

**How to create a computed properties or something I can use to achive this ?** I can't change the structure of those two arrays/objects, but I need to keep them updated of change in each way.

I tried to do this inside my vue instance:

```
computed: {
            layout: {
                get: function () {
                    let allPositions = [];
                for (var item of items) {
                    allPositions.push(
                        {
                            x: item .Position.x,
                            y: item .Position.y,
                            h: item .Position.Height,
                            w: item .Position.Width,
                            i: item .Id
                            //do not set here min/maxW and min/maxH
                        }
                    );
                }
                return allPositions;
                },
                set: function () {
                    ???
                }
            }

        },
```

But this will not work, I don't know how to really bind those properties together. Do you know how to do that ? I am right to use computed property to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I passed by something similar to this on my actual project.
I've searched about it and there is an option to watch deep, is the best option for array of arrays, array of objects, object of arrays, etc...

Should be something like this:

```
watch: {
     <variableName>: { // should be the name of the variable you want to watch
        // if you want, this handler() allows 2 params like (newValue, oldValue) to compare something if you want.
        handler() {
            // do your logic
            // call a function with the logic
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```